# SELinux removed but the kernel tries to load it at boot

Tags: selinux

Distro: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)

Can somebody help me: What are the sources of these files below? I purged SELinux* /etc/default/grub was cleaned of SELinux and I still received an error at boot.

```
 root@zika:/home/brad# dmesg |g selinux
    [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-31-generic root=UUID=2231b73b-cd11-4c0d-99fd-f8ba4a22b922 ro security=selinux quiet splash
    [    0.036834] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-31-generic root=UUID=2231b73b-cd11-4c0d-99fd-f8ba4a22b922 ro security=selinux quiet splash
    [    1.930280] evm: security.selinux
    root@zika:/home/brad# cat /proc/cmdline
    BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-31-generic root=UUID=2231b73b-cd11-4c0d-99fd-f8ba4a22b922 ro security=selinux quiet splash
```

/etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" "

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

and the /proc/cmdline which reproduces the change (I removed selinux and added apparmor):

```
root@zika:/etc# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-31-generic root=UUID=2231b73b-cd11-4c0d-99fd-f8ba4a22b922 ro security=apparmor quiet splash
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) which version of Ubuntu is currently on the machine (2) how was grub updated to not have SELinux? 

Comment: after purged SELinux, I removed SELinux from /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" "

Comment: Did you run `update-grub`?

Answer (score 0):

When you modify `/etc/default/grub`, you have to also run `sudo update-grub`.

This rebuilds the GRUB bootloader information and configurations from the `/etc/default/grub` file and other GRUB configuration files.

That then will stop trying to load SELinux on boot.

Comment: yes, I update-grub, that is strange to me because is still present somewhere.

Comment: Put the contents of your `/etc/default/grub` then into your question as an edit.  We can assist you finding what's misconfigured

Comment: The selinux was indeed in the grub loader, maybe someone will understand why, I removed it, and now is OK. I do not understand why update-grub did rebuild the bootloader but did not remove selinux as it was in /etc/default/grub

Comment: @BradThompson Revisions to `/etc/default/grub` are manual revisions - simply 'removing' SELinux packages from the system don't alter the GRUB defaults file

Comment: correct, but I removed manually selinux from /etc/default/grub and update-grub